# Python print out array into two results

Tags: python

I cant print out the second line

i tried to used divide by 2 and use two for loop to print it,

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
w=len(A)
T=w/2
for i in range(T):
  for ii in range(T):
    print A[ii]


A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

i want to print like `[1,2,3,4]` and `[5,6,7,8]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`slicing`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/):

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print(A[:len(A)//2])                # print(A[:4])
print(A[len(A)//2:])                # print(A[4:])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

**EDIT**:

For understanding;

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
w = len(A)

first_part = []
sec_part = []
count = 0                  # counter var to check for the first/sec half of list
for i in range((w)):
     if count < w//2:
          count += 1
          first_part.append(A[i])
     else:
      sec_part.append(A[i])

print(first_part)
print(sec_part)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

use list slicing:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print A[:len(A)/2]
print A[len(A)/2:]
```

Output would be:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(A[:int(len(A)/2)], A[int(len(A)/2):])
```